# Postpone execution of code inside document.ready()

Tags: jquery

I have a document.ready function that I am using to slide toggle and it looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    if ($("div[id='feature-content']").is(":visible")) {
    $("div[id='feature-content']").hide();
    $("div[id='feature-content']").slideToggle(9000).delay(4000);
    }

    $("div[id='feature-content']").slideToggle(9000).delay(4000);


    });

});
```

I want the slide toggle to occur only after say, 5 secs, after rendering the page. So I modified the above code by including a setTimeOut() like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    window.setTimeout(function() {

        if ($("div[id='feature-content']").is(":visible")) {
        $("div[id='feature-content']").hide();
        $("div[id='feature-content']").slideToggle(9000).delay(4000);
        }

        $("div[id='feature-content']").slideToggle(9000).delay(4000);


        });
    }
    ,
    15000
    );
});
```

But I am not able to get it to work. Can someone help me to accomplish my objective?

Thank you.

Comment: I was just testing with 15 secs. What I really need is 5 secs. Thank you.

Comment: The code that you have posted has mismatched brackets. I am presuming the first `});` is unnecessary?

Comment: Also, please clarify the effect you are aiming for: from the looks of the code, it seems like you are trying to slide the div down over 9 seconds, wait for 4 seconds, then slide it back up to be invisible again. Is that correct?

Comment: GregL: What I really want is for the toggle effect to begin 5 secs after the DOM is ready. Unfortunately what is happening is the toggle panel appears when going to the web page, and after a delay of 5 secs the panel disappears, and then toggling takes place. I want the panel to be hidden to start with. Any ideas? Please share. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `});` in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if ($("div[id='feature-content']").is(":visible")) {
            $("div[id='feature-content']").hide();
            $("div[id='feature-content']").slideToggle(9000).delay(4000);
        }

        // }); <<< This should not be here

        $("div[id='feature-content']").slideToggle(9000).delay(4000);
    }
    ,
    5000
    );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CnQ38/

If you're not already, please consider [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Chrome Console. Both would have told you about the extra code/syntax error.

Comment: Jared: Thank you very much for pointing me out the error. I will start using Firebug, never used until now. However, the problem I now have is the panel that I am trying to show and hide, appears when I visit the page to begin with and then the slide toggle happens after 5 secs. How do I make the panel not appear at all to begin with? I tried to add the code "$("div[id='feature-content']").hide();", but the slide toggle now stops working.